# Linux - Pyinstaller Error "failed to execute script " - Convert Python to ELF executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyinstaller, elf

I'm trying to make a linux executable from my python program with: pyinstaller --onefile tool.py, it doesn't work, I get an executable in the ./dist folder, I try to run it and I have the error "Failed to execute script {name}"

The program works fine with python 3 but the executable fail to run

Output of the executable **./dist/tool**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cryptodome'
[5912] Failed to execute script tool
```

the module Cryptodome is already installed but still Getting `No module named Cryptodome` in pyinstaller

Comment: Hi @lordOfSadi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a lot of details provided to us. While there is a lot of information, it sometimes may be overwhelming. Can you. please provide the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can help us address your problem. To help you modify your code, can you also read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @joe-ferndz, thanks for the remark,  I've updated the post .